# MediaWiki: How can I use the output of {{Special:Editcount/User}} in #expr?

Tags: parsing, mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-templates

I want to use the output of `{{Special:Editcount/User}}` in `#expr` to calculate something. But of course the output is handled as a string, even if I split it into its figures with `#sub`. So how can I make it being recognized as int? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{formatnum|{{Special:Editcount/<user>}}|R}}` ([docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Formatting)).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because embedded special pages such as {{Special:Editcount}} are filled out at load time, after the Wikitext has already been parsed. In order to parse such content you will need runtime JavaScript.